# How to import or export nagios host Data from command line

Tags: monitoring, scripting, host, icinga

This might be a basic question for some of you but being a beginner i wanted to know how to export or import data of the current status(CPU, Memory, Diskspace etc) of the host from command line into a CSV/JSON/XML format. THis is to provide daily reports in a readable format to our management team. Below is brief of what we are running,

We have a nagios server in the backend and we are using Icinga on the frontend to see host status, graphs etc. On the Icinga when i check the current status of the host i do see an option to "Export to CSV" in the browser but i wanted to get this data from the command line so i can automate this process for multiple hosts. 
Is there a way to simply run some commands and download the current status of a host(Windows or Linux) from command line?

Thanks and any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Just wanted to add the command i am using to give a clearer view of my problem,

curl -o test/test2 -u user:password http://10.0.0.1/icinga/cgi-bin/status.cgi/host=10.0.0.2&csvoutput

In the above URL 10.0.0.1 is the Icinga server and using the above URL i am trying to download data of host 10.0.0.2. This works but its downloading data of all the hosts currently running on Icinga. I only need data specific to the host and not for all the hosts on the Icinga server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Keith. I got it fixed. Just added double quotes to the URL and that did the job :)

curl -o test/test2 -u user:password "http://10.0.0.1/icinga/cgi-bin/status.cgi/host=10.0.0.2&csvoutput"

Answer (score 1):

[Icinga natively supports JSON output in status.cgi.](https://wiki.icinga.org/display/howtos/Using+JSON+export+in+Classic-UI)

By constructing the right filter arguments, you can get JSON of anything that status.cgi can display. For example, something like:

`status.cgi?hoststatustypes=3&serviceprops=2097162&servicestatustypes=20&jsonoutput`